# SQL - Update table after Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
(
 SomeID INT,
 OtherID INT,
 String VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20'
INSERT Testdata SELECT 4,  6, ''
INSERT Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4'
```

I managed to remove the comma using the Query below

```
Select A.SomeID
,B.*
From [filter].[dbo].[Testdata] A
Cross Apply (
Select RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select 
replace(A.String,',','§§Split§§')
as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) 
as A 

Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
) B
```

Now, what i wish is how to update the existing table with the new set of values.
Thank you.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values of integers in a string.  Use a junction/association table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I think that's actually the idea here. The trouble is just getting from A to B.

Comment: What kind of update semantics are you thinking of, though? Your new table has more rows than the old one. What should happen to `OtherID` -- should it be repeated in the new rows? Because there's not a 1-to-1 mapping between old and new, it would be easier to simply create a new table from your query, delete the old one and rename it (or delete/truncate/insert if you can't physically throw the table away). The only scenario where this wouldn't work is if you have foreign keys pointing to `Testdata`, but then your problem becomes more complicated anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i can omit OtherID and delete the old table and create a new table, that is not an issue. Then how should i create a new table with updated values ?

Comment: Best: `CREATE TABLE`, then `INSERT NewTable(SomeID, NewString) SELECT <your whole query>`. Easier: `SELECT [columns] INTO NewTable FROM ...` but that will create a table with no indexes or primary key at all, so you have to add those afterwards.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Testdata
    (
     SomeID INT,
     OtherID INT,
     String VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    INSERT Testdata SELECT 1,  9, '18,20,22'
    INSERT Testdata SELECT 2,  8, '17,19'
    INSERT Testdata SELECT 3,  7, '13,19,20'
    INSERT Testdata SELECT 4,  6, ''
    INSERT Testdata SELECT 9, 11, '1,2,3,4'

    CREATE TABLE NewData
    (
      SomeID INT,
      otherID int,
      String VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO  NewData (SomeID,OtherID,String)


    Select A.SomeID,OtherID,
    B.* 
    From [dbo].[Testdata] A
    Cross Apply (
    Select RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select 
    replace(A.String,',','§§Split§§')
    as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) 
    as A 

    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
    ) B


    Delete  from Testdata
    Insert Testdata (SomeID, OtherID , String)

    select SomeID, OtherID , String from NewData
```

Answer (score 2):

So since (in your comment) you say you want to create a new table that's pretty straight forward with your existing query

#### Pre SQL Server 2016

```
CREATE TABLE NewData
(
  SomeID INT,
  String VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO NewData
SELECT A.SomeID,
       B.*
FROM [dbo].[Testdata] A
Cross Apply (
Select RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select 
replace(A.String,',','§§Split§§')
as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) 
as A 
Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
) B

SELECT * FROM NewData
```

#### Post SQL Server 2016

You can now use `STRING_SPLIT` to get rid of your large SQL block

```
CREATE TABLE NewData2
(
  SomeID INT,
  String VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO NewData2
SELECT A.SomeID,
       S.value
FROM [dbo].[Testdata] A
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (A.String, ',') S

SELECT * FROM NewData2
```

You wont have any constraints etc, so you need to put these in your `CREATE TABLE` as you normally would.

*Note: You should really change your table definition so you are storing integers now rather than a varchar.*